# Docker for Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2017 Integration

Tags: docker, docker-machine

My objective is to have a development environment with docker and Kubernetes integrated with Visual Studio 2017 so that I can run the app on the docker container from directly within Visual Studio. I'm on a Windows 7 OS.

My research has taken me thus far:

1. Docker for Windows only supports Windows 10+. As an alternative, I can use Docker Toolbox which setups a Virtual Machine via Virtual Box and runs a Linux VM (boot2docker). Docker actually runs in this Linux VM and shares its executable with Windows 7 via environment variables.
2. Kitematic comes with Docker Toolbox and is essentially a GUI tool for managing my docker images.

Here are the questions, I'm trying to get answered and the issues I'm experiencing:

1. When I launch Kitematic, it says "Couldn't find a native setup" for docker. When I try to install Docker for Windows, clicking on the executable does nothing. **Is it impossible to install Docker natively on Windows 7 without a Virtual Machine in the middle**?
2. In using the Boot2Docker VM, it is a Linux distro and consequently, I can only use .NET core and ASP.NET core. **If I can't get a native Docker instance, is it possible to have a Boot2Docker Windows machine so I can utilize all of the .NET framework on it?**
3. I was finally able to build and run the docker image from Git Bash utilizing the Boot2Docker docker machine, but when I try to integrate with Visual Studio I get this error: `C:\Users\JoeTest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.1916590\build\Container.targets(222,5): error CTC1003: Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running.`

I've found various solutions that range from PowerShell to ensuring the C:/Users/ folder was shared between the Virtual Box image and Windows 7 host, but nothing seems to work for the VS Studio integration. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Created project in Visual Studio 2017 for ASP.NET core on Windows 7
2. Installed and Validated Docker Toolbox, e.g. can execute docker run hello-world
3. Closed the project in VS Studio and setup the following in Powershell:

   `docker-machine env 
   $Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1" 
   $Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
   $Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C\Users\JoeTest\.docker\machine\machines\default"
   $Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME = "default"
   $Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = "true"
   /# Run this command to configure your shell:
   /# & "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env | Invoke-Expression
   PS C:\Users\JoeTest> & "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env | Invoke-Expression`

   `invoke-item C:\Users\JoeTest\source\repos\VSEWebAppSample\VSEWebAppSample.sln`

This opens the Visual Studio Project.
4. Then, I type Ctrl + F5 and get the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: VSEWebAppSample, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>VSEWebAppSample -> C:\Users\JoeTest\source\repos\VSEWebAppSample\VSEWebAppSample\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\VSEWebAppSample.dll
1>VSEWebAppSample -> C:\Users\JoeTest\source\repos\VSEWebAppSample\VSEWebAppSample\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\VSEWebAppSample.Views.dll
1>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID debian.8-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\JoeTest\vsdbg\vs2017u5"
1>Info: Using vsdbg version '15.7.20425.2'
1>Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-x64'
1>Info: C:\Users\JoeTest\vsdbg\vs2017u5 exists, deleting.
1>Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' cou
1>ld not be found.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:47 char:13
1>+     Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
1>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.IO.Compression.FileSyste
1>   m:String) [Add-Type], Exception
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
1>   .AddTypeCommand
1>
1>Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:47 char:13
1>+     Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationExc
1>   eption
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
1>   ds.AddTypeCommand
1>
1>Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression' could not be f
1>ound.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:48 char:13
1>+     Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "System.IO.Compression"
1>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.IO.Compression:String) [
1>   Add-Type], Exception
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
1>   .AddTypeCommand
1>
1>Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:48 char:13
1>+     Add-Type <<<<  -assembly "System.IO.Compression"
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationExc
1>   eption
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
1>   ds.AddTypeCommand
1>
1>New-Object : Cannot find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]: make sure the
1> assembly containing this type is loaded.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:64 char:29
1>+     $zipArchive = New-Object <<<<  System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive -Argument
1>List $zipStream
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti
1>   on
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb
1>   jectCommand
1>
1>Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]: make sure that t
1>he assembly containing this type is loaded.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:65 char:46
1>+     [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions] <<<< ::ExtractToDirectory($zipA
1>rchive, $targetLocation)
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
1>   Extensions:String) [], RuntimeException
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
1>
1>You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:66 char:24
1>+     $zipArchive.Dispose <<<< ()
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dispose:String) [], RuntimeEx
1>   ception
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>
1>Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\JoeTest\vsdbg\vs2017u5\s
1>uccess_rid.txt'.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:97 char:26
1>+     $runtimeId | Out-File <<<<  -Encoding utf8 $SuccessRidFile
1>    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundExce
1>   ption
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ou
1>   tFileCommand
1>
1>Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\JoeTest\vsdbg\vs2017u5\s
1>uccess_version.txt'.
1>At C:\Users\JoeTest\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1:100 char:24
1>+     $version | Out-File <<<<  -Encoding utf8 $SuccessVersionFile
1>    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundExce
1>   ption
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ou
1>   tFileCommand
1>
1>Info: Successfully installed vsdbg at 'C:\Users\JoeTest\vsdbg\vs2017u5'
1>docker build -f "C:\Users\JoeTest\source\repos\VSEWebAppSample\VSEWebAppSample\Dockerfile" -t vsewebappsample:dev --target base "C:\Users\JoeTest\source\repos\VSEWebAppSample"
1>Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.471MB
1>
1>Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
1> ---> 40d759655ea3
1>Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> f82084d08a44
1>Step 3/4 : EXPOSE 49718
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 22d65a07b772
1>Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 44315
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 1a6aecd0e9f1
1>Successfully built 1a6aecd0e9f1
1>Successfully tagged vsewebappsample:dev
1> C:\Users\JoeTest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.1916590\build\Container.targets(222,5): error CTC1003: Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running.
```

One article I found said I needed to update my PowerShell version but I went to this link and was confused which option I should download. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I found that Visual Studio doesn't support Docker Toolbox. It only works with Native Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on win 7, you cannot use the current "docker for windows", which only works for win10 pro and server 2016.

Your only solution is to use the Docker Toolbox https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/.  Incidentally you must use it with Oracle's VirtualBox.  But you don't need any virtual machine to make this work.